# Menu and Autohide FloatingActionButton of Android Design Support Library

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library, floating-action-button

I'm using Android Design Support Library and I want a FloatingActionButton that have AutoHide by Scrolling,

my Layout is:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/LargeText" />
    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/scrollView"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_rating_star_off_mtrl_alpha" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

FloatingActionButton always showing when scrolling text, i want to autohide it when scrolling text.

And, I want to have a FloatingActionButton Menu by clicking on FloatingActionButton, like this:

[image]

Comment: check this link it may help you https://guides.codepath.com/android/Floating-Action-Buttons

Comment: you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30701458/2022000

Comment: How did you show the text next to the fab ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> FloatingActionButton that have AutoHide by Scrolling,

You must use `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`. You can't use the ScrollView. You have to use the NestedScrollView or a view that implements the NestedScrollingChild interface, like a RecyclerView.

To achieve this kind of pattern you have to implement your custom `Behavior`. There is a nice code posted by a Googler that hides the FAB when the user scrolls down and shows it when they scroll back up. Reuses the same animation that FloatingActionButton.Behavior uses for hiding/showing the FAB in reaction to the AppBarLayout exiting/entering.

**UPDATED 18/07/2015**

With the **22.2.1** you can simply add the code posted below, using the pre-built animations.
Just use a class like this: (original source [here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/compare/master...ianhanniballake:scroll_aware_fab))

```
public class ScrollAwareFABBehavior extends FloatingActionButton.Behavior {
    public ScrollAwareFABBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(final CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, final FloatingActionButton child,
                                       final View directTargetChild, final View target, final int nestedScrollAxes) {
        // Ensure we react to vertical scrolling
        return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL
                || super.onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, directTargetChild, target, nestedScrollAxes);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(final CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, final FloatingActionButton child,
                               final View target, final int dxConsumed, final int dyConsumed,
                               final int dxUnconsumed, final int dyUnconsumed) {
        super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);
        if (dyConsumed > 0 && child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            // User scrolled down and the FAB is currently visible -> hide the FAB
            child.hide();
        } else if (dyConsumed < 0 && child.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
            // User scrolled up and the FAB is currently not visible -> show the FAB
            child.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can apply this behaviour to your FAB using:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
     app:layout_behavior="com.support.android.designlibdemo.ScrollAwareFABBehavior" />
```

With **Design 22.2.0**:
You have to use a class like this: (original source [here](https://github.com/ianhanniballake/cheesesquare/commit/aefa8b57e61266e4ad51bef36e669d69f7fd749c))

```
public class ScrollAwareFABBehavior extends FloatingActionButton.Behavior {
    private static final Interpolator INTERPOLATOR = new FastOutSlowInInterpolator();
    private boolean mIsAnimatingOut = false;

    public ScrollAwareFABBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(final CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, final FloatingActionButton child,
                                       final View directTargetChild, final View target, final int nestedScrollAxes) {
        // Ensure we react to vertical scrolling
        return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL
                || super.onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, directTargetChild, target, nestedScrollAxes);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(final CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, final FloatingActionButton child,
                               final View target, final int dxConsumed, final int dyConsumed,
                               final int dxUnconsumed, final int dyUnconsumed) {
        super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);
        if (dyConsumed > 0 && !this.mIsAnimatingOut && child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            // User scrolled down and the FAB is currently visible -> hide the FAB
            animateOut(child);
        } else if (dyConsumed < 0 && child.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
            // User scrolled up and the FAB is currently not visible -> show the FAB
            animateIn(child);
        }
    }

    // Same animation that FloatingActionButton.Behavior uses to hide the FAB when the AppBarLayout exits
    private void animateOut(final FloatingActionButton button) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
            ViewCompat.animate(button).scaleX(0.0F).scaleY(0.0F).alpha(0.0F).setInterpolator(INTERPOLATOR).withLayer()
                    .setListener(new ViewPropertyAnimatorListener() {
                        public void onAnimationStart(View view) {
                            ScrollAwareFABBehavior.this.mIsAnimatingOut = true;
                        }

                        public void onAnimationCancel(View view) {
                            ScrollAwareFABBehavior.this.mIsAnimatingOut = false;
                        }

                        public void onAnimationEnd(View view) {
                            ScrollAwareFABBehavior.this.mIsAnimatingOut = false;
                            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }).start();
        } else {
            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(button.getContext(), R.anim.fab_out);
            anim.setInterpolator(INTERPOLATOR);
            anim.setDuration(200L);
            anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    ScrollAwareFABBehavior.this.mIsAnimatingOut = true;
                }

                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    ScrollAwareFABBehavior.this.mIsAnimatingOut = false;
                    button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(final Animation animation) {
                }
            });
            button.startAnimation(anim);
        }
    }

    // Same animation that FloatingActionButton.Behavior uses to show the FAB when the AppBarLayout enters
    private void animateIn(FloatingActionButton button) {
        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
            ViewCompat.animate(button).scaleX(1.0F).scaleY(1.0F).alpha(1.0F)
                    .setInterpolator(INTERPOLATOR).withLayer().setListener(null)
                    .start();
        } else {
            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(button.getContext(), R.anim.fab_in);
            anim.setDuration(200L);
            anim.setInterpolator(INTERPOLATOR);
            button.startAnimation(anim);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can apply this behaviour to your FAB using:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
     app:layout_behavior="com.support.android.designlibdemo.ScrollAwareFABBehavior" />
```

Of course you can change this code to obtain your favorite pattern.

> And, I want to have a FloatingActionButton Menu by clicking on FloatingActionButton, like this:

Currently the original FAB doesn't support this pattern. You have to implement a custom code to achieve it.

Comment: This is not worked for scrollView. I'm try this code, but it's work just for ViewPager.

Comment: You can't use the ScrollView. You have to use the NestedScrollView or a view that implements the NestedScrollingChild interface, like a RecyclerView.

Comment: For whatever reason, `dyConsumed` always returned `0` for me in `onNestedScroll`, so the animation never ran. I switched it for `dyUnconsumed` and now it runs as expected.

Comment: @AliSh where did you found `R.anim.fab_in` and `R.anim.fab_out` animation?

Comment: `design_fab_out` and `design_fab_in` are located in `<sdk>/extras/android/support/design/res/anim/`.

Comment: How to add this library to android studio

Comment: OnNestedScroll() and onStartNestedScroll() are now deprecated

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it

Here's my code.

Step 1:

First make Getter of FloatingActionMenu so that you can call it from another activity or from fragment where your recycleview is used

```
public FloatingActionMenu getFloatingActionMenu() {
        return fabMenu;
    }
```

Step 2:

Call below line from another activity or from fragment

```
   FloatingActionMenu fabMenu=((MainActivity)getActivity()).getFloatingActionMenu();
```

Step 3:

Now Check wheather recycleview is scrolling or not depend on "dy" position 
    Here I have used animation fabMenu

```
Animation FabMenu_fadOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
            R.anim.fade_out);
Animation  FabMenu_fadIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
            R.anim.abc_grow_fade_in);

recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if (dy > 0 && floatingActionButton.isShown()) {
                    //fabMenu.startAnimation(FabMenu_fadIn);
                    fabMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                if (dy < 0 && !floatingActionButton.isShown()) {
                   // fabMenu.startAnimation(FabMenu_fadOut);
                    fabMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Note : If you want to hide FloatingActionButton on scroll then use same code as in FloatingActionMenu.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement floating action menu using [this](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button).

Regarding the animation for floating action menu, you can create a class called ScrollAwareFloatingActionMenuBehaviour:

```
public class ScrollAwareFloatingActionMenuBehaviour extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<FloatingActionsMenu> {
    private static final Interpolator INTERPOLATOR = new FastOutSlowInInterpolator();
    private boolean mIsAnimatingOut = false;
    private boolean mIsAnimatingIn = false;

    public ScrollAwareFloatingActionMenuBehaviour(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionsMenu child, View dependency) {
        return dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionsMenu child, View dependency) {
        float translationY = Math.min(0, dependency.getTranslationY() - dependency.getHeight());
        child.setTranslationY(translationY);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
                                       FloatingActionsMenu child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
        return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL ||
                super.onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, directTargetChild, target,
                        nestedScrollAxes);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionsMenu child,
                               View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
        super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed,
                dyUnconsumed);

        if (dyConsumed > 10 && !this.mIsAnimatingOut && !this.mIsAnimatingIn && child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            // User scrolled down and the FAB is currently visible -> hide the FAB
            animateOut(child);
        } else if (dyConsumed < -10 && !this.mIsAnimatingOut && !this.mIsAnimatingIn && child.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
            // User scrolled up and the FAB is currently not visible -> show the FAB
            animateIn(child);
        }
    }

    // Same animation that FloatingActionButton.Behavior uses to hide the FAB when the AppBarLayout exits
    private void animateOut(final FloatingActionsMenu button) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
            ViewCompat.animate(button).translationYBy(200F).alpha(0.0F).setInterpolator(INTERPOLATOR).withLayer()
                    .setListener(new ViewPropertyAnimatorListener() {
                        public void onAnimationStart(View view) {
                            ScrollAwareFloatingActionMenuBehaviour.this.mIsAnimatingOut = true;
                        }

                        public void onAnimationCancel(View view) {
                            ScrollAwareFloatingActionMenuBehaviour.this.mIsAnimatingOut = false;
                        }

                        public void onAnimationEnd(View view) {
                            ScrollAwareFloatingActionMenuBehaviour.this.mIsAnimatingOut = false;
                            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }).start();
        } else {
            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(button.getContext(), R.anim.design_fab_out);
            anim.setInterpolator(INTERPOLATOR);
            anim.setDuration(200L);
            anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    ScrollAwareFloatingActionMenuBehaviour.this.mIsAnimatingOut = true;
                }

                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    ScrollAwareFloatingActionMenuBehaviour.this.mIsAnimatingOut = false;
                    button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(final Animation animation) {
                }
            });
            button.startAnimation(anim);
        }
    }

    // Same animation that FloatingActionButton.Behavior uses to show the FAB when the AppBarLayout enters
    private void animateIn(FloatingActionsMenu button) {
        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
            ViewCompat.animate(button).translationYBy(-200F).alpha(1.0F)
                    .setInterpolator(INTERPOLATOR).withLayer().setListener(new ViewPropertyAnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(View view) {
                    ScrollAwareFloatingActionMenuBehaviour.this.mIsAnimatingIn = true;

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(View view) {
                    ScrollAwareFloatingActionMenuBehaviour.this.mIsAnimatingIn = false;

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(View view) {
                    ScrollAwareFloatingActionMenuBehaviour.this.mIsAnimatingIn = false;

                }
            })
                    .start();
        } else {
            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(button.getContext(), android.support.design.R.anim.design_fab_in);
            anim.setDuration(200L);
            anim.setInterpolator(INTERPOLATOR);
            button.startAnimation(anim);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that R.anim.fab_in and R.anim.fab_out are replaced by R.anim.design_fab_in and R.anim.design_fab_out respectively.

Use it in the xml:

```
<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
        xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/fab_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/colorAccent"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/colorAccentLight"
        fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_behavior="com.example.widgets.behaviour.ScrollAwareFloatingActionMenuBehaviour"
        fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style"
        fab:fab_labelsPosition="left">

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_share"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/fab_normal_blue"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/fab_normal_blue_pressed"
            fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_social_share"
            fab:fab_title="@string/fab_menu_group_chat" />

</com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>
```