# FAB does not animate - test code and screenshot attached

Tags: android, android-animation, repeat, floating-action-button

I have prepared [a simple test project at GitHub](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/q35/MyCoordinator) for my question:

[image: app screenshot]

I am trying to show/hide a `FloatingActionButton` (aka FAB) every 5 seconds by the following code in [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q35/MyCoordinator/app/src/main/java/de/afarber/mycoordinator/MainActivity.java):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mFab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    mInAnimation = AnimationUtils.makeInAnimation(this, false);
    mInAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            mFab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    mOutAnimation = AnimationUtils.makeOutAnimation(this, true);
    mOutAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            mFab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }
    });

    run();
}
```

The `Runnable` output ("Toggle animation") appears every 5 seconds in ADB logs, but the FAB is always visible:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    Log.d("MyCoordinator", "Toggle animation");
    mFab.setAnimation(mFab.isShown() ? mOutAnimation : mInAnimation);
    mHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
}
```

Does anybody please know, what is missing here?

Also I am curious, if it's possible to define the above animations in the [activity_main.xml](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q35/MyCoordinator/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml) instead of Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather use `mFab.startAnimation(mFab.isShown() ? mOutAnimation : mInAnimation)` than `mFab.setAnimation(mFab.isShown() ? mOutAnimation : mInAnimation);`. With `setAnimation` you have to define the start time of your animation (which is probably what you are missing)

Comment: That was it, thank you (+1) Do you think this animation can be defined in XML?

Comment: it should be possible, with an `set`. I don't have much experience though. You can have a look to one the animation defined by the system. Then one part of `android.R.anim`